# Unhiding div by link from another page in JQUERY

Tags: jquery

I have a bunch of accessories in separate hidden divs in an "accessory page."  I want the link in another page to go to the accessory page and unhide that specific accessory div. I have been playing with JQUERY code but nothing is working so far. I'm new to JQUERY.

page 1 link:

```
products/accessories.html#lens
```

accessories page html:

```
                    <div class="card data lens">
                        <img class="d-block mx-auto" src="/images/products/acc/lens.jpg" alt="lens">
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <a href=#lens></a>
                        <h3>Lens cover</h3>
                        <p class="c-text">This is my lens cover</p>
                        <ul>
                          <li>It's a great lens cover</li>
                        </ul>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card data bag">
                      <img class="d-block mx-auto" src="/images/products/acc/bag.jpg" alt="Bag">
                      <div class="card-body">
                          <a href="#bag"></a>  
                          <h3>Camera Bag</h3>
                          <p class="c-text">Great bag!</p>
                          <ul>
                            <li>2 left in stock</li>
                          </ul>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card data cloth">
                      <img class="d-block mx-auto" src="/images/products/acc/cloth.jpg" alt="Cloth">
                      <div class="card-body">
                          <a href="#cloth"></a>
                          <h3>Cloth</h3>
                          <p class="c-text">Great Cloth</p>
                          <ul>
                            <li>Sizes available: in large</li>
                          </ul>
                      </div>
                    </div>
```

accessories page JQUERY:

```
<script>
if (location.hash !== null && location.hash !== "") {
  $(location.hash + ".data").show();
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  
      $(".data").hide();
      $("." + $(this).val()).fadeIn(700);
  }).change();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="card data" id="lens">
    <img class="d-block mx-auto" src="/images/products/acc/lens.jpg" alt="lens">
    <div class="card-body">
        <a class="link-to-section" href=#lens></a>
        <h3>Lens cover</h3>
        <p class="c-text">This is my lens cover</p>
        <ul>
            <li>It's a great lens cover</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="card data" id="bag">
    <img class="d-block mx-auto" src="/images/products/acc/bag.jpg" alt="Bag">
    <div class="card-body">
        <a class="link-to-section" href="#bag"></a>
        <h3>Camera Bag</h3>
        <p class="c-text">Great bag!</p>
        <ul>
            <li>2 left in stock</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="card data" id="cloth">
    <img class="d-block mx-auto" src="/images/products/acc/cloth.jpg" alt="Cloth">
    <div class="card-body">
        <a class="link-to-section" href="#cloth"></a>
        <h3>Cloth</h3>
        <p class="c-text">Great Cloth</p>
        <ul>
            <li>Sizes available: in large</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="application/javascript">
    function loadThisCard(cardID, changeTheHash=false) {
        // hide all the cards
        $('.data').hide();
        // update the hash without reloading the page
        if (changeTheHash) {
            history.pushState(null,null,cardID);
        }
        // load the correct card
        $('.data' + cardID).fadeIn(700);
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        // hide all the cards on load
        $('.data').hide();
        // get all of your links
        let linksArray = [];
        let currentHash = location.hash;
        console.log(currentHash);
        $('.link-to-section').each(function() {
            // add it to our array
            linksArray.push($(this).attr('href'));
        });
        // stop the page from scrolling to the anchor if it's one of your anchors, and load the card
        if (linksArray.includes(currentHash)) {
            setTimeout(function() { window.scrollTo(0, 0); }, 1);
            // load the correct card with our function
            loadThisCard(currentHash);
        }
    });

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I tried making a link using your example by using the "href" you provided for the lens div. I made the link products/accessories.html#lens and put it in another page but when you click on it the page does not show the "lens" div.  I even added "#" to the href (<a href="#lens>) to see if it would make a difference but it didn't.  Do you have any suggestions? Did it work for you, clicking a link from another page and getting the sole div from the href or id to show up?

Comment: If this only ever needs to run once per page then my solution overcomplicates it. That would make sense given the link is in the div we're hiding. Give me a minute to make a better code segment here. :)

Comment: Updated to add a working example. Sorry for the delay. Work got in the way. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks so much Clayton, you're awesome!!.  I'm still trying to understand the code but it works!  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

In my eyes you made a classical mistake in your javascript. The mistake is that first javascript lines is executed when the browser reach the codelines. To this timepoint your requested element does not exist yet.

try:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{  
  if (location.hash !== null && location.hash !== "") {
    $(location.hash + ".data").show();
  }

  $(".data").hide();
  $("." + $(this).val()).fadeIn(700);
}).change();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var top_of_element = $("#element").offset().top;
  var bottom_of_element = $("#element").offset().top + $("#element").outerHeight();
  var bottom_of_screen = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).innerHeight();
  var top_of_screen = $(window).scrollTop();

  if ((bottom_of_screen > top_of_element) && (top_of_screen < bottom_of_element)){
    console.log('true')
  } else {
    console.log('false')
  }
});
```